# Join two tables and then pull Distinct Records

Tags: sql, join

I'm writing a VS 2010 program in C# and I've ran into a SELECT statement in SQL that is taking me to long to figure out and could use some help.

```
Table 1 - mailfiles
id,fname,lname,etc...

Table 2 - details,
id,timestamp,page_id,mailfile_id(FK),campaign_id
```

I want to pull the unique/distinct mailfile_id sorted by the most current timestamp and then join them to the mailfiles table to get the rest of my info.

I had something like this,

```
SELECT mailfiles.id,mailfiles.fname,mailfiles.lname,mailfiles.company2,mailfiles.city,etc...
FROM mailfiles
JOIN
(SELECT DISTINCT(details.mailfile_id)
FROM details
GROUP BY details.mailfile_id) as TMP
ON mailfiles.id = TMP.mailfile_id
ORDER BY TMP.mailfile_id DESC
```

Which gets me the distinct/unique records but I don't have access to the details columns, which I want to display the timestamp.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Nick

Comment: Why not just add `, MAX(timestamp) AS timestamp` to the subquery?

Comment: So for mailfiles, there could be multiple with the same id and you only want to pull the one out with the latest timestamp, or...?  I'm trying to logic through what you need and there seems to be some logical inconsistencies in your request...

Comment: No, mailfiles only has unique records, the details is where multiple occurances of that mailfile id is being recorded, this is to track where and how many times a person landed on a web pages. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yea, that helps, one second, let me change my answer up..

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
SELECT * 
FROM
(SELECT mailfile_id, Max(timestamp) m_timestamp FROM details GROUP BY mailfile_id) AS latest
INNER JOIN details on latest.mailfile_id = details.mailfile_id AND latest.m_timestamp = details.timestamp
INNER JOIN mailfiles ON mailfiles.id = details.mailfile_id
ORDER BY details.timestamp
```

There's an unresolved ambiguity in the case that there are two identical timestamps, but it seems that's something that would have to be solved in any case.  For a given id, which of these 2 timestamps is actually the latest?

Comment: I'm running this query now but I think this may be it! Thanks Lucent!

Comment: That's great!  Mark as answer for the next person that comes through?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MAX (timestamp), fname, lname, ...
FROM mailfiles m, details d
WHERE m.id. = d.mailfiles_id 
GROUP BY m.id, fname, lname, ...
```

Hm - yes, I see the problem rising - do you need more than timestamp from the details? Then it get's more tricky.

```
SELECT m.*, d.* 
FROM mailfiles m, details d 
WHERE m.id = d.mailfiles_id 
  AND (d.mailfiles_id, d.timestamp) IN (
    SELECT mailfiles_id, MAX (timestamp) 
    FROM details 
    GROUP BY mailfiles_id);
```

If you need details from both tables.

I don't know whether your database supports `... and (a, b) in (SELECT c, d FROM ...`; postgresql does.

Comment: You're right, I added the trivial grouping, but maybe, if we need more infos from `detail`, it's more complicated.

Comment: -1 for suggesting implicit join syntax that has been outdated for almost 20 years and shoul dnot be used in new code.

Comment: Yes, I would like to grab some other fields

Comment: HLGEM: Implicit joins is outdated syntax? Do you have evidence for that claim? I only know JOINS as an alternative syntax.

Comment: The former is ANSI 89 syntax, the latter is ANSI 92.  In some DBMSs joining in the where clause is deprecated.  You can no longer perform outer joins in the where clause only with LEFT/RIGHT OUTER JOIN.  You'll actually get an error.

Comment: For MS SQL Server you can view the deprication in a table here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143729.aspx

Comment: a) MS-SQL has not been the topic here. However, at the given link I just find one statement about joins, `Use of *= and =*` - I don't see how it is related to the question at hand.

Comment: The [msdn-site has another page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191517.aspx), where you'll find a `WHERE a.fkey = b.pkey`-query, introduced is the paragraph with the statement, that explicit JOINS are `preferred` which is very different from the other being outdated.

Comment: @HLGEM [Here is the current postgresql-help page](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/queries-table-expressions.html), Please read 7.2.2: ... The join condition of an inner join can be written either in the WHERE clause or in the JOIN clause. ... and so on.

Comment: @user unknown, yes you can, you should not.

Comment: @HLGEM: Did you read "The JOIN syntax in the FROM clause is probably not as portable to other SQL database management systems, even though it is in the SQL standard." on the postgresql site?

Comment: Name me a database that you might port to (which is a fairly rare occurance anyway) that doesn't support the explicit syntax? I would not permit anyone to use code like this on my databases and you should not be encouraging other people to use it either. There are problems with implicit joins that do not exist with explicit joins. They are BAD CODE and their use should not be encouraged.

Comment: Which problems? I'm not using 'some implicit joins' but a specific one, so you can directly tell me, what problem there is with my code, not with some code you can imagine. What you permit on your database is your problem, not mine. And please stop shouting.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid what you want to do is quite tricky since as you've found out the distinct operator works on all the fields you list in the query.  If it works for you, you could return a list of ID's using your first query and then use these ID's to retrieve the details that your require in a second query.  I know its two queries, but it may end up being faster than a large complex query anyway.